# Convert 'obtain impulse response code' from python to matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I am attempting to convert a python code to Matlab. The code functions is to get impulse response from original and recorded signal. The python code is obtained from [Joseph](https://github.com/josephernest/impulseresponse.py). I believe the rewritten code is the same as the python code. However the impulse response obtained from python and Matlab is different. What have I done wrong here? Hope to hear some advice and criticism.

[image: Comparison of impulse response from python(left) and matlab(right)]

Comparison of impulse response from python(left) and matlab(right)

**impulseresponse.m [Matlab]**

```
[a,fs] = audioread('sweep.wav'); % sweep
[b,fs] = audioread('rec.wav'); % rec

a = pad(a,fs*50,fs*10);
b = pad(b,fs*50,fs*10);
[m,n] = size(b);
h = zeros(m,n); 

for chan = 1:2
    b1 = b(:,chan);
    b1 = filter20_20k(b1,fs);
    ffta = fft(a);
    fftb = fft(b1);
    ffth = fftb ./ ffta;
    h1 = ifft(ffth);
    h1 = filter20_20k(h1,fs);
    h(:,chan) = h1;
end

h = h(1:10*fs,:);
dB = 40;
h = h*power(10,dB*1.0/20);
h(:,1) = h(:,1) ./ max(abs(h(:,1))); % normalizing impulse response
h(:,2) = h(:,2) ./ max(abs(h(:,2)));
figure;
plot(h)
```

**pad.m [should function the same as padarray in the python code]**

```
function y = pad(data, t_full, t_pre)
[row_dim,col_dim] = size(data);
t_post = t_full - row_dim - t_pre;
if t_post > 0
    if col_dim == 1
        y = [zeros(t_pre,1);data;zeros(t_post,1)];
    else
        y1 = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(:,1);zeros(t_post,1)];
        y2 = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(:,2);zeros(t_post,1)];
        y = [y1,y2];
    end 
else
    if col_dim == 1
        y = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(1:t_full - t_pre,1)];
    else
        y1 = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(1:t_full - t_pre,1)];
        y2 = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(1:t_full - t_pre,2)];
        y = [y1,y2];
    end
end
end
```

**filter20_20k.m [should function the same as filter20_20k(x,sr)]**

```
function y = filter20_20k(x,fs)
nyq = 0.5*fs;
[z,p,k] = butter(5,[20.0/nyq,20000.0/nyq],'bandpass');
sos = zp2sos(z,p,k);
y = sosfilt(sos,x);
end
```

**python code by Joseph Ernest**

```
SWEEPFILE = 'sweep.wav'
RECFILE = 'rec.wav'
OUTPUTFILE = 'IR.wav'

import wavfile
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

def ratio(dB):
    return np.power(10, dB * 1.0 / 20)

def padarray(A, length, before=0):
    t = length - len(A) - before
    if t > 0:
        width = (before, t) if A.ndim == 1 else ([before, t], [0, 0])
        return np.pad(A, pad_width=width, mode='constant')
    else:
        width = (before, 0) if A.ndim == 1 else ([before, 0], [0, 0])
        return np.pad(A[:length - before], pad_width=width, mode='constant')

def filter20_20k(x, sr): # filters everything outside out 20 - 20000 Hz
    nyq = 0.5 * sr
    sos = signal.butter(5, [20.0 / nyq, 20000.0 / nyq], btype='band', output='sos')
    return signal.sosfilt(sos, x)

sr, a, br = wavfile.read(SWEEPFILE, normalized=True)
sr, b, br = wavfile.read(RECFILE, normalized=True)

a = padarray(a, sr*50, before=sr*10)
b = padarray(b, sr*50, before=sr*10)
h = np.zeros_like(b)

for chan in [0, 1]:
    b1 = b[:,chan]

    b1 = filter20_20k(b1, sr)
    ffta = np.fft.rfft(a)
    fftb = np.fft.rfft(b1)
    ffth = fftb / ffta
    h1 = np.fft.irfft(ffth)
    h1 = filter20_20k(h1, sr)

    h[:,chan] = h1

h = h[:10 * sr,:]
h *= ratio(dB=40)

wavfile.write(OUTPUTFILE, sr, h, normalized=True, bitrate=24)
```

Comment: A good approach to find errors when converting code to another language is to evaluate intermediate results or to test parts of your code independently

Comment: @m7913d From your suggestion, I tried to see the values by printing the values. But due to large array size (9.6 Million), it got stuck. So I tried plotting it on a graph but this error appear `OverflowError: In draw_path: Exceeded cell block limit`. I have no issue viewing the results on matlab but not python. How should I change my attempt?

Comment: Test your code with a small example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to convert [Joseph's impulseresponse.py python codes](https://github.com/josephernest/impulseresponse.py) to matlab now. Putting here for future possibility of people using it.

**impulseresponse.m**

```
[a,fs] = audioread('sweep.wav'); % sweep
[b,fs] = audioread('rec.wav'); % rec

a = pad(a,fs*50,fs*10);
b = pad(b,fs*50,fs*10);
[m,n] = size(b);
h = zeros(m,n); 

for chan = 1:2
    b1 = b(:,chan);
    b1 = filter20_20k(b1,fs);
    ffta = rfft(a);
    fftb = rfft(b1);
    ffth = fftb ./ ffta;
    h1 = irfft(ffth);
    h1 = filter20_20k(h1,fs);
    h(:,chan) = h1;
end

h = h(1:10*fs,:);
dB = 40;
h = h*power(10,dB*1.0/20);

audiowrite('heck.wav',h,fs,'BitsPerSample',24);
[y,fs] = audioread('heck.wav');
figure;
plot(y)
```

**pad.m**

```
function y = pad(data, t_full, t_pre)
[row_dim,col_dim] = size(data);
t_post = t_full - row_dim - t_pre;
if t_post > 0
    if col_dim == 1
        y = [zeros(t_pre,1);data;zeros(t_post,1)];
    else
        y1 = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(:,1);zeros(t_post,1)];
        y2 = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(:,2);zeros(t_post,1)];
        y = [y1,y2];
    end 
else
    if col_dim == 1
        y = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(1:t_full - t_pre,1)];
    else
        y1 = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(1:t_full - t_pre,1)];
        y2 = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(1:t_full - t_pre,1)];
        y = [y1,y2];
    end
end  
end
```

**filter20_20k.m**

```
function y = filter20_20k(x,fs)
nyq = 0.5*fs;
[z,p,k] = butter(5,[20.0/nyq,20000.0/nyq],'bandpass');
sos = zp2sos(z,p,k);
y = sosfilt(sos,x);
end
```

**rfft.m and irrft.m**

Go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778504/what-is-numpy-fft-rfft-and-numpy-fft-irfft-and-its-equivalent-code-in-matlab). Credit goes to Dmitri Chubarov.