# What is numpy.fft.rfft and numpy.fft.irfft and its equivalent code in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, fft

I am converting a python code into MATLAB and one of the code uses numpy rfft. In the documentation of numpy, it says real input.

> Compute the one-dimensional discrete Fourier Transform for real input.

So what I did in MATLAB is using abs but the results are different.

Python code

```
ffta = np.fft.rfft(a)
```

MATLAB code

```
ffta = abs(fft(a));
```

What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The real FFT in numpy uses the fact that the fourier transform of a real valued function is so to say "skew-symmetric", that is the value at frequency `k` is the complex conjugate of the value at frequency `N-k` for `k=1..N-1` (the correct term is *Hermitian*). Therefore `rfft` returns only the part of the result that corresponds to nonpositive frequences.

For an input of size `N` the `rfft` function returns the part of the FFT output corresponding to frequences at or below `N/2`. Therefore the output of `rfft` is of size `N/2+1` if `N` is even (all frequences from `0` to `N/2`), or `(N+1)/2` if `N` is odd (all frequences from 0 to `(N-1)/2`). Observe that the function `floor(n/2+1)` returns the correct output size for both even and odd input sizes.

So to reproduce `rfft` in matlab

```
function rfft = rfft(a)
     ffta = fft(a);
     rfft = ffta(1:(floor(length(ffta)/2)+1));
end
```

For example

```
a = [1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1];
rffta = rfft(a)
```

would produce

```
rffta =

 Columns 1 through 3:

   0.00000 + 0.00000i   2.00000 - 4.82843i   0.00000 + 0.00000i   

 Columns 4 through 5:

   2.00000 - 0.82843i   0.00000 + 0.00000i
```

Now compare that with python

```
>>> np.fft.rfft(a)
array([ 0.+0.j        ,  2.-4.82842712j,  0.-0.j        ,  
        2.-0.82842712j,  0.+0.j        ])
```

#### Reproducing irfft

To reproduce basic functionality of `irfft` you need to recover the missing frequences from `rfft` output. If the desired output length is even, the output length can be computed from the input length as `2 (m - 1)`. Otherwise it should be `2 (m - 1) + 1`.

The following code would work.

```matlab
function out = irfft(x, even)
    if nargin == 1
        even = true;
    end
    % `n`: the output length
    % `s`: the variable that will hold the index of the highest
    %      frequency below N/2, s = floor((n+1)/2)
    N = numel(x);  % function assumes 1D input
    if even
        n = 2 * (N - 1);
        s = N - 1;
    else
        n = 2 * (N - 1) + 1;
        s = N;
    end
    outf = zeros(1, n);
    outf(1:N) = x;
    outf(N+1:n) = conj(x(s:-1:2));
    out = ifft(outf);
end
```

Now you should have

```
>> irfft(rfft(a))
ans =

   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000
```

and also

```
abs( irfft(rfft(a)) - a ) < 1e-15
```

For odd output length you get

```
>> irfft(rfft(a(1:7)),even=false)
ans =

   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000  -1.0000  -1.0000  -1.0000
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I also want to reproduce `irfft`, i used 2*(m-1) but it shows index exceed matrix dimensions. Should i put it at a new topic?
`function irfft = irfft(a)`
`iffta = ifft(a);`
`irfft = iffta(1:(2*(length(iffta)-1)));`
`end`

Comment: what is the purpose of `-a` and `< 1e-15`?

Comment: @iHateUni `irfft(rfft(a))` should be equal to `a` if it were not for the numerical precision. So `abs(x-y) < 1e-15` means `x` almost equals `y` up to some accumulated rounding error with double precision numbers.

Comment: For rfft, it has to be `rfft = ffta(1:(((length(ffta)+1)/2));` :)

Comment: @iHateUni good point. Note that `floor(n/2)+1` equals `n/2+1` for even numbers and `(n+1)/2` for odd numbers, so the code we have above should work without any changes.