# What is the difference between numpy.fft.fft and numpy.fft.rfft?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, signal-processing, fft

The documentation says that `np.fft.fft` does this:

> Compute the one-dimensional discrete Fourier Transform.

and `np.fft.rfft` does this:

> Compute the one-dimensional discrete Fourier Transform for real input.

I also see that for my data (audio data, real valued), `np.fft.fft` returns a 2 dimensional array of shape (number_of_frames, fft_length) containing complex numbers.

For `np.fft.rfft` returns a 2 dimensional array of shape (number_of_frames, ((fft_length/2) + 1)) containing complex numbers. I am led to believe that this only contains *nonredundant FFT bins*.

Can someone explain in more depth the difference between the commands and why the shape of the returned array is different. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is numpy.fft.rfft and numpy.fft.irfft and its equivalent code in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778504/what-is-numpy-fft-rfft-and-numpy-fft-irfft-and-its-equivalent-code-in-matlab)

Comment: I don't want to know the difference between the fft and its inverse, and this is python not matlab

Comment: I know it's not MATLAB, but the basic concepts of fft is the same.

Comment: Fair enough, i am reading through the answers now. Thank you

Comment: Okay sure, glad to be of any help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basic difference is explained [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html) via example. As it says:

```
import numpy as np

data = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]

print("FFT output\n", np.fft.fft(data))
print("RFFT output\n", np.fft.rfft(data))
```

will result in:

```
FFT output
 [ 4.        +0.j         -2.11803399-1.53884177j  0.11803399+0.36327126j
  0.11803399-0.36327126j -2.11803399+1.53884177j]
RFFT output
 [ 4.        +0.j         -2.11803399-1.53884177j  0.11803399+0.36327126j]
```

> *Notice how the **final element** of the **fft output** is the complex*
>   *conjugate of the second element, for real input. For **rfft**, this*
>   *symmetry is exploited to compute only the **non-negative frequency***
>   *terms*.

Answer (score 26):

the reason is  explained in the docs:

> When the DFT is computed for purely real input, the output is
>   Hermitian-symmetric, i.e. the negative frequency terms are just the
>   complex conjugates of the corresponding positive-frequency terms, and
>   the negative-frequency terms are therefore redundant. This function
>   does not compute the negative frequency terms, and the length of the
>   transformed axis of the output is therefore n//2 + 1.

As a consequence, the algorithm is optimized and rfft is twice as fast. Furthermore, the spectrum is easier to plot :

```
In [124]: s=abs(sin(arange(0,2**13,3)))

In [125]: sp=rfft(s)

In [126]: plot(abs(sp))
```

[image]

Comment: I like the plot addition to the answer and so upvoted you. If we were to plot the complex conjugates, would that just be symmetrical over the amplitude axis?

Comment: Yes it will be. Not useful. So I fell rfft more convenient.

Comment: I feel dumb, but where +/- 1 comes from? Why not NFFT/2 ?

Comment: since  the frequency are proportional to  -n,-n+1,.....-1,0,1,... n-1,n. the +1 is for the central term which is is own symetric.